# Javascript regex, add suffix to class attributes in html

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I need a simple regex to transform a string that contains valid html nodes like

`<p class="paragraph-class">First paragraph</p>`

to

`<p class="paragraph-class-xxx">First paragraph</p>`

Notice the `-xxx` at the end

`myHtmlString.match(/class="(.*?)"/g);`

That returns correctly an array which contains `['class="paragraph-class"']`

I can then do i guess, 
`myHtmlString.replaceAll('class="paragraph-class"','class="paragraph-class-xx"')`

But if i have 2 classes or more i also need to do some trickery.

Is there a way to do this with a simple straight-forward regex, with elements that can contain multiple classes

`<p class="class1 class2 class3"></p>`

Comment: Did you look into javascript classList()?

Answer (score 0):

If the element exists in the DOM you can use `classList.replace()` to replace the class list. The assumption is that there is only one element with such a class name.

```
document.querySelector('.paragraph-class').classList.replace('paragraph-class', 'paragraph-class-xxx');
```